# How can I limit the GUI choices in the drop-down menu at login?

Tags: 12.04, login, gui

Having installed GNOME-shell, Cinnamon, and GLX/Cairo-dock, the drop-down GUI list at login is now quite long (3 GNOME options, 3 GLX options, 2 Unity, and 2 Cinnamon). I only plan on using a few of these options, and it would be great to remove the other clutter from the menu. So far, I have not found a way to do this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. Just move the undesired session files from the directory `/usr/share/xsessions` to another directory.

The quick way to do so is, typing `gksu nautilus` in the dash prompt ( pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> ) and hit Enter. It will open nautilus with root power. Go to the `/usr/share/xsessions` folder and remove or move the appropriate file in another directory.

You can open those files to determine which file actually needs moving. Use gedit to open them. For example, you may want to remove "Gnome / Openbox" or "KDE / Openbox" files to another dir.

Comment: Thank you! I figured there had to be a simple solution out there I was missing...

Comment: Ah, I did not see that there. Can you tell it's my first question? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can remove those options you don't use by removing their corresponding packages.